# Understanding AT commands?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, at-command

I paired a phone to an android device , but there is a problem in the response of some AT commands:

```
""" I get an incoming call to the paired phone then i executed random commands"
AT+BLDN
AT+CLCC
AT+CMOD
```

I have read some informations about the AT commands but I still not understanding if those commands are executed from the paired phone side or from the device to which i paired the phone ?
So if i get problems in AT commands response, shall i consider it as a phone issue or the android device issue?

Comment: The AT commands are sent from your code to the device to which you paired. What those commands mean is dependent on your device, and the device manufacturer should provide documentation as to what commands the device accepts and what they mean.

Comment: If you simply goggle for _AT commands_ you will get many references to general information about AT commands.

Comment: Do you want to understand what device is executing the commands? Add `AT+CGMI` and `AT+CGMM`. The first one returns the manufacturer identification, the second the model name. In this way, if you know the vendor and the model of both cellular and bluetooth devices, you are able to understand who executes the commands.

Comment: It looks like these are Hands-Free Profile commands. You have to study Bluetooth HandsFree Profile specification. Bluetooth roles concept is little confusing, Audio Gateway (AG) role generally means mobile phone, HandsFree (HF) role generally means headset, handsfree, car headunit etc.

Answer (score 1):

The AT commands are something that is being processed on your device. Not only BT modules understand AT commands, there are others like WiFi (ESP8266, for instance) or GSM modules that read those.

So usually they are read, interpreted and executed by your chip.

Can you send AT commands as a bluetooth payload? Yes you can! Is it common practice? I don't think so

Then we must fully understand how your device and phone are interacting with eachother to be able to definitively answer **yes it's the phone** or **no, it's just your device**.

Reading the manuals of your device would help a lot, but for what you've been providing I would say you're doing something wrong with the AT commands

Comment: To sum up your ‘answer’ you’re saying ‘read the manual’, with no explanation at all and zero links to online references at all. IMO this is not actually an answer.

Comment: I cannot provide you with any reference because you don't provide any useful information to help you trace the error. Every single chip has it's own AT commands and they are not necessarily shared or may have different behavior. I am afraid I can't give you any references if I don't know: what error you're getting, what BLE device are you using, are you finishing your AT commands with \r\n? Does the manual require you to do so?  I have too many unknowns. Sorry to not be so helpful here